# Regex for getting flashvars

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get `flashvars` from a string which is in the code below.
But at the end of the code the matched value comes with other attributes like `pluginspage`.
How can I fix it?
Am I wrong with my regex?

Here is my code:

```cs
string source = "<embed src=\"http://godtube.com/flvplayer.swf\" FlashVars=\"videoThumb=http://www.godtube.com/thumb/1_30772.jpg&flvPath=http://www.godtube.com/flvideo1/47/30772.flv\" wmode=\"transparent\" quality=\"high\" width=\"330\" height=\"270\" name=\"flv_demo\" align=\"middle\" allowScriptAccess=\"sameDomain\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" /></embed>";
Regex sRgx = new Regex("flashvars=\"(.*)\"", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match regexMatch = sRgx.Match(source);
if (regexMatch.Success)
{
    string matched = regexMatch.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
Regex sRgx = new Regex("flashvars=\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

The `?` makes the regex to match the shortest possible match, otherwise the .* will crunch everithing to the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Make the * lazy by adding a ? after it.
There are other alternatives too, I'd suggest you reading this article:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html
Specially the "An Alternative to Laziness" clause.